# APEX: Charts in Tabs Container not visible

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, anychart

I have in APEX a 'Static content' region. This has the template 'Tabs container'. As subregions (or 'tabs' as it is called within this template) I have multiple charts. The problem is that just the chart of the active tab is displayed correctly. When selecting another tab, the chart within the selected tab is not display. I have to resize the browser window, then the chart is displayed.

I'm using the default APEX Theme (42) without changes.

Is this an APEX bug or am I doing something wrong? If this is bug, is there a workaround?

Link to question in Oracle Community Forum: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3947770?sr=inbox&ru=289068

Thanks for your answers,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by the following two steps:

1. Replace the *Tab Container* region with a *Region Display Selector* region. This region is like a tab menu. All regions that should be shown in the tab menu need to have the flag 'Region Display Selector'. All the regions that are handled by the *Region Display Selector* should be on the same hierarchical level as the *Region Display Selector*.
2. The main error still exists but for Region Display Selectors, APEX fires an event for which you can write a handler:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.apex-rds').data('onRegionChange', function(mode, activeTab) {
      $(window).trigger("apexwindowresized");
    });
});`

The handler fires an event that the browser window size has been changed on which the charts automatically act and redraw everything.

This should also work for the *Crousel Container*. A big thanks goes to this blog entry: https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2016/05/02/working-with-region-display-selectors-in-apex-5-0/